# Can you draw multiple Bitmaps on a single View Method?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-animation

currently I am trying to make an animation where some fish move around. I have successfully add one fish and made it animate using canvas and Bitmap. But currently I am trying to add a background that I made in Photoshop and whenever I add it in as a bitmap and draw it to the canvas no background shows up and the fish starts to lag across the screen. I was wondering if I needed to make a new View class and draw on a different canvas or if I could use the same one? Thank you for the help!
Here is the code in case you guys are interested:

```
public class Fish extends View {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    float x, y;

    public Fish(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fish1);

        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);

        if (x < canvas.getWidth())
        {
            x += 7;
        }else{
            x = 0;
        }
        invalidate();

            }

    }
```

Comment: are there any bitmap loading errors when you try to load the background bitmap?  perhaps it's too big of an image..

Comment: @Buddy No there are no loading errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw as many bitmaps as you like.  Each will overlay the prior.  Thus, draw your background first, then draw your other images.  Be sure that in your main images, you use transparent pixels where you want the background to show through.

In your code, don't call Invalidate() - that's what causes Android to call onDraw() and should only be called from somewhere else when some data has changed and needs to be redrawn.

You can do something like this, where theView is the view containing your animation:

In your activity, put this code in onCreate()

```
myAnimation();
```

Then

```
private void myAnimation()
{
  int millis = 50; // milliseconds between displaying frames
  theView.postDelayed (new Runnable ()
  {
    @Override public void run() 
    {  
      theView.invalidate();  
      myAnimation();  // you can add a conditional here to stop the animation
    }
  }, millis);
}
```

Comment: Should I use a while loop instead of invalidate to animate it then?

Comment: Let me know if it worked.  I updated my answer a couple times because I realized it had some errors.  Should be good now.

Comment: It can go pretty much anywhere.  I'm not sure how you want to start and stop it.  I suggested onCreate() because that will cause it to start when the app start.  No provision for stopping (although it will be suspended while the app is paused).

Comment: Ok and just one more thing just to be clear, so I should put my animation in theView method and delete the onDraw Method right?

Comment: You still need onDraw() - that's where you actually draw the bitmaps.  It's the invalidate() that needs to go elsewhere.

Comment: So I should create a theView method in my View class? Then I should add the animation there?

Comment: Ok Nevermind I got it thanks again for your help bro